# Ionic social sharing with deep links

Tags: ionic-framework

I’m using deeplinks and i share the URL with the social sharing plugins, the issue is that the link isnt sent as a string not a link.

Example

```
this.socialSharing.shareViaFacebook(msg + " myapp://home/article/"+id, img).then(() => {
//
});
```

I tried a script on codepen and its working perfectly.